# Django: How do you avoid polluting the parent context in an inclusion tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

Here's the code I'm trying to make work:

```
from django import template
from copy import copy
register = template.Library()

# Renders the site header.
@register.inclusion_tag('site/tags/header.tpl', takes_context=True)
def header(context):
    # Load up the URL to a certain page.
    url = Page.objects.get(slug='certain-page').url

    # Pass the entire context from our parent into our own template, without polluting
    # our parent's context with our own variables.
    new_context = copy(context)
    new_context['page_url'] = url
    return new_context
```

Unfortunately, this still pollutes the context of the template that calls this inclusion tag.

```
<div id="content">
  {% header %}
  HERE'S THE URL: {{ page_url }}
</div>
```

The `page_url` will still be rendered after "HERE'S THE URL:", because the parent context has been polluted.

How do I avoid that, while still being able to pass the full parent context into my template, with new variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
new_context = {'page_url': url}
new_context.update(context)
return new_context
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This *almost* worked! The only thing I had to do was call `flatten()` on the context object, since it's a `RequestContext`. Even though those act like dictionaries, they apparently can't be passed to `dict.update()`. `flatten()` reduces the RequestContext to an actual dict.

Comment: Correct, I believe this stands true for all `Context` subclasses. However, I recommend you only pass what you need. No need to copy a bunch of variables if you ain't going to use them all in the template! :)

Comment: Funny, I got here because I'm ___trying___ to pollute my parent context from an inclusion tag, and not having much success.

Answer (score 1):

Before updating the existing context, `push()` it onto the stack. After having rendered your template with a modified context, `pop()` it to restore the previous values.

This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context.pop).